# AWS: Unable to configure profiles in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had issues in accessing S3 buckets from EC2. I deleted both `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials` files. Now, when I try to create the profiles again, I get this long list of exceptions:

```
$ aws configure --profile dev
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line
>   27, in 
>       sys.exit(main())   File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 23, in main
>       return awscli.clidriver.main()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 50, in main
>       return driver.main()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 176, in
>   main
>       parser = self._create_parser()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 157, in
>   _create_parser
>       command_table = self._get_command_table()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 91, in
>   _get_command_table
>       self._command_table = self._build_command_table()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 111, in
>   _build_command_table
>       command_object=self)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line
>   672, in emit
>       return self._events.emit(event_name, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356,
>   in emit
>       return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228,
>   in emit
>       return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211,
>   in _emit
>       response = handler(**kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/customizations/preview.py",
>   line 70, in mark_as_preview
>       service_name=original_command.service_model.service_name,   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 351, in
>   service_model
>       return self._get_service_model()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 368, in
>   _get_service_model
>       api_version = self.session.get_config_variable('api_versions').get(   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line
>   234, in get_config_variable
>       logical_name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/configprovider.py",
>   line 227, in get_config_variable
>       return provider.provide()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/configprovider.py",
>   line 324, in provide
>       value = provider.provide()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/configprovider.py",
>   line 383, in provide
>       config = self._session.get_scoped_config()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line
>   335, in get_scoped_config
>       raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name) botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (dev) could
>   not be found [~] aws configure --profile dev Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 27, in 
>       sys.exit(main())   File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 23, in main
>       return awscli.clidriver.main()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 50, in main
>       return driver.main()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 176, in
>   main
>       parser = self._create_parser()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 157, in
>   _create_parser
>       command_table = self._get_command_table()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 91, in
>   _get_command_table
>       self._command_table = self._build_command_table()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 111, in
>   _build_command_table
>       command_object=self)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line
>   672, in emit
>       return self._events.emit(event_name, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356,
>   in emit
>       return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228,
>   in emit
>       return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211,
>   in _emit
>       response = handler(**kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/customizations/preview.py",
>   line 70, in mark_as_preview
>       service_name=original_command.service_model.service_name,   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 351, in
>   service_model
>       return self._get_service_model()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 368, in
>   _get_service_model
>       api_version = self.session.get_config_variable('api_versions').get(   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line
>   234, in get_config_variable
>       logical_name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/configprovider.py",
>   line 227, in get_config_variable
>       return provider.provide()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/configprovider.py",
>   line 324, in provide
>       value = provider.provide()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/configprovider.py",
>   line 383, in provide
>       config = self._session.get_scoped_config()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line
>   335, in get_scoped_config
>       raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name) botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (dev) could
>   not be found

Comment: This specific doc page might help you https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/getting_started.html#getting_started_prerequisites

Answer (score 1):

Its failing because you deleted those directories and like the error mentions, it can't find the profile.

You have to run:

```
$ aws configure
```

Answer (score 0):

I manually updated `~/.aws/config` file. This resolved the issue.

Comment: There's no need to create it manually, `aws configure` will create that file for you.

Comment: yes, true...But for some reason, `aws configure` didn't work for me.

Comment: But did you try from a fresh terminal?